# How to disable a tab in bottom navigation view?

Tags: android, android-bottomnav

I have 4 tabs in my app. In which one is accessible without log-in but others can't be. So, I need to implement a functionality in which if a user clicks on that tab then rest 4 will be disabled and when I click on those tabs I only want toast but if I click on those tabs I get toast but it also got selected but fragment not changed. I want to disable that tab
I have assigned a value to a variable to check whether it is without logging or after logging.

Code:

```
  case R.id.home:
                if(value.equals("1")){
                    Toast.makeText(CarerSeekerActivity.this,R.string.login_signup,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    navigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setEnabled(false);

                }
                else {
                    fragment = new CreatePersonalizedPackageCareSeekerFragment();
                    changeFragments(fragment);
                }
                return true;
```

but it is showing toast and but selected that tab. I do not want to make it selected. Please help.

Comment: try `view.setEnabled(false)`. it would actually be more helpful to see more of the switch code though and what views you are using.

Comment: I tried but it disabled for second time not for first.

Comment: @mishti means you want to handle click based condition, right?

Comment: Yes @HemantN.Karmur

Comment: @mishti can you please tell me that from where this value 1 comes?

Comment: @mishti you can manage this based on condition. When you get the click of tab check that your condition is matching true or not.

Comment: @mishti no need to disable.

Comment: @HemantN.Karmur i get value one if it is without login to disable tabs

Comment: did you try to debug and check?

Comment: @mishti okay got it.

Comment: @mishti no need to disable the tabs, just check your login condition into tab click listener. If it's without login then do nothing or if it's logged in then do some action needed in that tab.

Comment: @HemantN.Karmur but when I click on that tab it does not change fragmnet but got selected. I also do not want to make it selected.

Comment: @mishti please check my answer I have updated.

Answer (score 3):

After setting the menu please write below code in your on create method:

```
if(isloggedin){
// do click action which is required if the user already logged in
change your fragment from here
}else{
    bottomnavigation.getMenu().getItem(your_position).setEnabled(false); // disable menu if user not logged in
Toast.makeText(CarerSeekerActivity.this,R.string.login_signup,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I have used BottomNavigationView for this

Comment: @mishti please check my answer this is working fine.

Comment: @mishti got it?

Comment: @mishti you have to put this code in onCreate method after setting a menu then an then this will be working fine.

Comment: if (value.equals("1")) {
                        navigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setEnabled(false);
                        Toast.makeText(CarerSeekerActivity.this,R.string.login_signup,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        fragment = new CreatePersonalizedPackageCareSeekerFragment();
                        changeFragments(fragment);
                    }

Comment: @mishti check my answer, I have changed it as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm replying 3 years later, but this is the function I've done for changing all the tabs to clickable or not clickable. You can easily adapt it for what you asked.

```
private void setNavigationBarClickableItems(BottomNavigationBar bottomNavigationBar, boolean clickable) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) bottomNavigationBar.getChildAt(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < menuView.getChildCount(); i++)  {
        menuView.getChildAt(i).setClickable(clickable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This sets the clickable for all the children under `menuView`, but the OP wants a specific one to be set clickable/non-clickable.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt correct, like I said it can be easily adapted though. Should be enough to access the corresponding index in the children of menuView, for getting the one he wanted to disable instead of iterating; or to insert a condition inside the iteration, for doing a check based on the id of the button or something similar.